# GSUB and Forward Slash usage in Ruby

Tags: ruby, gsub

I often see the gsub function being called with the pattern parameter enclosed in forward slashes. For example:

```
>> phrase = "*** and *** ran to the @@@."
>> phrase.gsub(/\*\*\*/, "WOOF")
=> "WOOF and WOOF ran to the @@@."
```

I thought maybe it had something to do with escaping asterisks, but using single quotes and double quotes works just as well:

```
>> phrase = "*** and *** ran to the @@@."
>> phrase.gsub('***', "WOOF")
=> "WOOF and WOOF ran to the @@@."

>> phrase.gsub("***", "WOOF")
=> "WOOF and WOOF ran to the @@@."
```

Is it just convention to use forward slash?  What am I missing?

Comment: If you don't want to do the work of escaping, you may help yourself with `Regexp.escape("***")` (The result is `\*\*\*`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use forward slashes if you need to use regular expressions.

If you use a string argument with `gsub`, it will just do a plain character match.

In your example, you need backslashes to escape the asterisks when using a regular expression, because asterisks have a special meaning in regex (optionally match something any number of times). They are not necessary when using a string, because they are just matched exactly.

In your example, you probably don't need to use a regular expression, since it is a simple pattern. However, if you wanted to match `***` only when it was at the beginning of a string (e.g. the first bunch in your example), then you would want to use a regex, for example:

```
phrase.gsub(/^\*{3}/, "WOOF")
```

For more information on regular expressions, see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

For more information on using regular expressions in Ruby, see: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html.

To play with regular expressions as they work in Ruby, try: http://rubular.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing reading the documentation:

> The pattern is typically a Regexp; if given as a String, any regular expression metacharacters it contains will be interpreted literally, e.g. '\d' will match a backlash followed by ‘d’, instead of a digit.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub

In other words, you can give a string or a regular expression. Regular expressions can be delimited several ways:

> Regexps are created using the /.../ and %r{...} literals, and by the Regexp::new constructor.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Regexp.html

The benefit of  `%r` and of the alternate `%r` delimiters is you can usually find a delimiter that doesn't collide with characters in the pattern, which would force escaping them, as in your example.

`*` has to be escaped because it has special meaning in a regex, but in a string it does not.